# Trying to inject values into a publisher, but receiving unordered values

Tags: ios, swift, macos, reactive-programming, combine

This is an oversimplification of what I'm trying to achieve using combine.
I need to inject a value into a shared publisher if something happen.
Here you see that if the number 2 is received by map I use the send command on the original publisher to inject the number 3.
I would expect to receive a sequence of number but instead I receive the number 3 before the event that triggered it.

```
let pub = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()

let pubSharered = pub.share().eraseToAnyPublisher()

let anyCanc = pubSharered
.map { value -> Int in
        switch value {
        case 2:
            pub.send(3)
            return value
        default:
            return value
        }
}.sink { (value) in
    print("Sink: \(value)")
}

pub.send(0)
pub.send(1)
pub.send(2)
pub.send(4)
```

The output is: `0,1,3,2,4` what I was expecting is `0,1,2,3,4`.
Can someone explain it?

Comment: As I have seen your code, under "case 2:" you have perform two operations 1st is "pub.send(3)" and 2nd "return 2" that's why in the output first return 3 before return 2.

Comment: If you want the output as 0,1,2,3,4 then there are two options either use fallthrough for case 2 or you can use the "defer"  block of code under case2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a use case for `flatMap`. You can flat map to a `Publishers.Sequence<[Int], Never>` like this:

```
let anyCanc = pubSharered
    .flatMap { value -> Publishers.Sequence<[Int], Never> in
        switch value {
        case 2:
            return [value, 3].publisher // value, plus a 3
        default:
            return [value].publisher // change nothing
        }
}.sink { (value) in
    print("Sink: \(value)")
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank for your answer. While your snippet does the trick, my simple code is an over simplification of a real code where I'm using `flatMap` already. The issue with that snippet is that only "anyCanc" would be informed with number 3. Since pubShared has more subscribers around the actual code, I'd like that any other subscriber could receive that injected value by keeping the sequence order.

Comment: @Andrea What about `share`ing the flat mapped publisher instead?